# Azure AD B2C - Verify user when transacting

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

We are leveraging Azure AD B2C Custom policies with our web application. When we do an important transaction on the app, even if the user is logged in, we would like to be able to verify that this is the correct user before committing the transaction. For instance, we could send a code to the user's phone and ask him to enter the code in the app (on the form he is executing the transaction).

Is this something achievable thru Azure AD B2C Custom policies ? MFA phone factor extension?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Azure Multi-Factor Authentication Software Development Kit (SDK) can let you build two-step verification directly into transaction processes of applications in your Azure AD tenant.

For the details about the code sample, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-sdk).

Note: This feature will no longer be supported until November 14, 2018.

Comment: Is there anything supported with azure b2c custom policies?

Comment: Later there is the new of MFA for this, I will update the new solution here.